How do I import Image sequence (broken?) or not working Blender 4.1
I'm trying to animate a face, but I'm stuck because of the issue I've screenshot below. I've checked the Animated Image Sequences button, but the issue persists.
What I see during the import:

Result I get after clicking Import Images as Planes:


Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See How to upload an image to a post? or GIF

Could you please explain why the images appear so dark? I'm puzzled by how this could happen. I increased the exposure/brightness for you. But I'm curious how you managed to get them so dark?

I have a dimmer app installed on my PC that adds extra darkness to the screen because having to navigate monitor options is kind of annoying, but ill remember to disable it for a screenshot next time. Thank you!

Looking at the images so far, I cannot see the filenames of your image sequence. If they do not have a continuous sequence of numbers as suffix in the filename like "pic0001", "pic0002", pic0003" etc. but have gaps inbetween like "pic0001", "pic0004", "pic0007" or completely different filenames like "image0001", "pic0002", "picture0003", then Blender does not recognize them as an image sequence but instead assumes you just want to import multiple images as planes. That is why you get several planes, each with its own image on it.

This turned out to be exactly what I was looking for, Thanks! I renamed all the images and they became one single plane.
